# Validating objects in Django with multiple forms

Tags: django, validation, forms

Using [this example](http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/). Pretend there are date fields in both forms. How would you write a custom clean for validation to compare both dates? I have added an example clean at the bottom which returns a key error on poll.

models and forms

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    target_date= models.DataTimeField()

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    target_date= models.DataTimeField()
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
To start, we’ll need forms for each model.

from django import forms
from mysite.polls.models import Poll, Choice

class PollForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Poll

class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        exclude = ('poll',)
```

Views

```
from mysite.polls.models import Poll, Choice
from mysite.polls.forms import PollForm, ChoiceForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def add_poll(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pform = PollForm(request.POST, instance=Poll())
        cforms = [ChoiceForm(request.POST, prefix=str(x), instance=Choice()) for x in range(0,3)]
        if pform.is_valid() and all([cf.is_valid() for cf in cforms]):
            new_poll = pform.save()
            for cf in cforms:
                new_choice = cf.save(commit=False)
                new_choice.poll = new_poll
                new_choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/add/')
    else:
        pform = PollForm(instance=Poll())
        cforms = [ChoiceForm(prefix=str(x), instance=Choice()) for x in range(0,3)]
    return render_to_response('add_poll.html', {'poll_form': pform, 'choice_forms': cforms})
```

Example clean being ran on the form which returns the key error for poll.

```
def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            raise forms.ValidationError("")
        data = self.cleaned_data
        choiceDate = data["target_date"]
        pollDate = data["poll"]    ##--- The key error happens here
        if choiceDate > pollDate.target_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your dates do not match")
        return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pollDate = data["poll"]    ##--- The key error happens here`

That's because the form has no field called `poll` because your're explicitly excluding it in the form definition. I can't tell the clean you give is on the `PollForm` or the `ChoiceForm`, but neither has a `poll` field.

Comment: Correct, but I am setting the value with the following code. Is this the wrong way to do it?   -    for cf in cforms:
                new_choice = cf.save(commit=False)
                new_choice.poll = new_poll
                new_choice.save()

Comment: Yeah, but you're setting that value AFTER clean() has been called by is_valid() and clean() is still trying to access a field that just is not present in the form instance...

Comment: True, what would be the right way to accomplish this? I see what's wrong but haven't figured out a way to rewrite it to work correctly.

Comment: You can't cross validate between forms. Validation happens within their cleaning methods. What you could do is, in the view, test what you get back out of cleaned_data and then act on it/not act on it accordingly and show an appropriate error message with the messages framework.

Comment: Gotcha, I guess it's time to dig into the built in django admin site and see how they handel doing the same thing. Thanks for the help.